# Need help in improving SOQL performance

Tags: soql, performance

I have a SOQL query as below (where clause only). This query is not performing upto the mark, may be because of like operator. How can I substitute this :-

```
Where 
( 
abc__c = 'chris' OR 
xyz__c = 'jones' 
) 
AND 
( 
Name like : 'doodle%' 
OR BillingStreet like : 'doodle%' 
OR BillingCity like : 'doodle%' 
OR BillingState like : ''doodle%' 
OR BillingPostalCode like : 'doodle%' 
OR BillingCountry like : 'doodle%' 
OR stats__c like : 'doodle%' 
)
```

Comment: Could SOSL be an alternative ? + Is there a timeframe you can query for ? LastModified and Created date are indexed fields which improve your query speed.

Comment: How many records do you have in this table? It may be worth casting a broader net with your query and performing post-query filtering using a library like [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector). It will definitely help if you can add an indexed field somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using SOSL, such as:

```
FIND {doodle*} 
IN ALL FIELDS 
RETURNING 
Account(Id... WHERE abc__c = 'Chris' OR xyz__c = 'Jones')
```

You'll still probably want to compare the results to make sure you have valid matches. ALL FIELDS will search everywhere in the account, including the description field, etc. You'll get up to 2,000 results back, but you'll probably find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Apply the first where clause i.e.Where ( abc__c = 'chris' OR xyz__c = 'jones' )  and store the result in a temporary list. Now apply a for loop on this temporary list.

    For(listobj obj:templist)
    {
    If(obj.Name like : 'doodle%' OR obj.BillingStreet like : 'doodle%' OR obj.BillingCity like : 'doodle%' OR obj.BillingState like : ''doodle%' OR obj.BillingPostalCode like : 'doodle%' OR obj.BillingCountry like : 'doodle%' OR obj.stats__c like : 'doodle%')
     {
     finallist.add(obj);
    }
    }
```